# Unique name combos out of 2 files

Tags: powershell, unique

I know similar questions have been asked quite a few times before but in all the research i did online all i was able to find was questions about getting unique combos from a single array and so on but that i can do but what i'm looking for is a bit different.

I have a script that generates names by getting firstnames from a txt.file and surnames from another and then randomly creates a name, the script generates duplicates as well, so i was wondering, how can i get the number of all the possible unique combos? 
Considering that each text.file has 20 items (lastnames file has 20 items.

this is my script:

```
$FirstName = Import-Csv C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Firstname.txt -Delimiter ';' -Header Name, Gender
$LastName = Get-Content  C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Lastnames.txt
[array]$FirstNameMan = $null
[array]$FirstNameWoman = $null



[int]$NumberOfCombinations = Read-Host 'Enter the number of combinations you wish'
[string]$Gender = Read-Host 'Gender: Enter "M" for "man" or "W" for "woman"'

# here i split the names by gender
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $FirstName.Count; $i++) {
if ($FirstName[$i].Gender -like 'mann') {
    $FirstNameMan += $FirstName[$i].Name
}
else {
    $FirstNameWoman += $FirstName[$i].Name
}
}
#random join
  For ($j = 0; $j -lt $NumberOfCombinations; $j++) {
if ($Gender -like 'm') {
    $FirstNameMan[(Get-Random $FirstNameMan.Count)] + ', ' + $Lastname[(Get-Random $Lastname.Count)] 
}
else { 
    $FirstNameWoman[(Get-Random $FirstNameWoman.Count)] + ', ' + $Lastname[(Get-Random $Lastname.Count)] 
}
}
```

the result would be something like this(based on the chosen gender):

```
Katja, Schult
Mary, Krüger
Ruth, Meier
Ruth, Bauer
Katja, Bauer
Katja, Schneider
Mascha, Möller
Ruth, Schröder
Sara, Meier
```

now how can i find out how many possible unique combinations one could have?
(*not* unique would be when you get the same name combo twice, otherwise it is unique)
i think i just can't seem to find the logic to figure out an algorithm

sorry if this is too subjective

Comment: You can pipe your output to `Sort-Object -Unique` to get the unique list. Then you can use the count property of that output array: `($output | Sort-Object -Unique).count`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but surely the number of possible names is the number of first names (possibly restricted to M or F) multiplied by the number of last names.  If you have 3 first names (a,b,c) and 2 last names (d,e), there are only 6 (i.e. 3x2) possible names (ad,ae,bd,be,cd,ce) you can make (assuming they must be 'first last').  The fact that you are picking the names at random doesn't make any difference to this limit.

Comment: @boxdog, you're right mate, i already know that tho, but you're only missing that i'm not asking about how to do that mathmatically, i want to know how it's done using PS

Answer (score 1):

Generating all unique combinations of two unique lists is as easy as writing a nested loop:

```
$AllMaleNames = foreach($first in $FirstNameMan){
    foreach($last in $Lastname){
        "$first, $last"
    }
}

$AllFemaleNames = foreach($first in $FirstNameWoman){
    foreach($last in $Lastname){
        "$first, $last"
    }
}
```

Now you can pick from those lists instead:

```
if($Gender -like 'm') {
  $NamesToPickFrom = $AllMaleNames
}
else {
  $NamesToPickFrom = $AllFemaleNames
}

$NamesToPickFrom | Get-Random -Count $NumberOfCombinations
```